# compare values in a column and find if there is an increment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a question. 
I am trying to find if there is an increment or decrement of sales by comparing the sales of 4 months.

How do we do this in sql.

```
Months  Sales
----    -----
jan       30
feb       10
mar       60
april     20
april     20
```

Comment: What is the desired results you want to get from this sample data?

Comment: I want to create a report. I want to mark an indicator as increased or decreased based on this table. I do not have any target value so that i can compare against. I want to compare against the previous months and come to conclusion as increased or decreased

Comment: Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: Why does april appear twice? What is your actual table structure including datatypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make query like below :

```
SELECT  MonthId,
    CASE WHEN Sales < (SELECT Sales FROM TestTable WHERE MonthId = TT.MonthId - 1) THEN 'Decremented' ELSE 'Incremented' END
FROM TestTable TT
```

where you should have int value in MonthId column, otherwise you need to create function which returns int value for passed month name or use case structure.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I will manage an int value. Do you have nay idea on how we can put an indicator in the SSRS for this column . Say if have to say if the sales has increased for that year ? by taking all the values ?

Comment: In SSRS, you can check this flag for increment/decrement and display indicator based on it. Just change text from "Increment" to 1 and "Decrement" to -1 in query.